# Get the values of a related model in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want get all the images of a product in the serialized form. My models are as below.

```
class Product():
    title 
    subtitle 
    ...
class ProductImage():
    product = models.ForeignKey(
    'Product', related_name='images', verbose_name=_("Product"))
    image_path
```

My serializers :

```
class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ('caption', 'display_order', 'original', 'product')


class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    images = ProductImageSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'title', 'slug', 'short_description', 'description',
            'sku', 'pk', 'images')
```

I am getting this error

> AttributeError at /api/products/
>   Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `display_order` on serializer `ProductImageSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'display_order'.

How do I get all the images for a particular product ?

Answer (score 2):

You should define a source of related model instances and set `many=True`:

```
images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True, source='images.all')
```

Comment: still getting Attribute error : I am querying using `related_name(images)` (see productimage model, I changed it). My query : `images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True, source='product_images.all')`

Comment: Now getting : `The fields option must be a list or tuple or "__all__". Got str.`

Comment: The point is you have to define a source. I may be wrong about syntax, maybe it should be just ```source='images'```.

Comment: ok. in shell if i do `product.images.all()` i get a queryset with all the image objects. is it a problem of serializing of those image objects ?

Comment: Not at all, you just have to find out correct syntax to do that. Probably this part of the official tutorial will help: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly